# Date field in CSV not recognized by Excel

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I am creating a .CSV file in which one of the fields is a Date. One of the rows of my .CSV looks like this

```
Ryan,Adams,Ryan Adams,"""reddish"" brown,yellow,""bluish"" green",May 12, 1995
```

Excel does not recognize that the last field is a date and splits into two fields `May 12` and `1995`

I tried adding quotes `"May 12, 1995"` but that means it is just copied as a string and that is not what I want. I want the Excel cell to recognize that it is a date.

Comment: That is some bad CSV you've got there; the first rule of CSV is that fields containing commas *must* be enclosed within quotes. Regards the date, you are going to have to change the date format in the file to something Excel understands, or manipulate the string once it's imported.

Comment: Are you able to reformat that date as 12-May-1995.  That would take the extra comma out of the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than changing your CSV file to have a recognizable date format, e.g. 1995-05-12, you could import the data as it stands and then convert the two parts to a valid date using the following formula.

```
=DATE(F1,MONTH(E1),DAY(E1))
```

This assumes that the "MMM-DD" part is in cell E1 and the YYYY part is in cell F1.

Then you can copy the new column, "paste values" over the top of itself to turn it into data, and delete columns E & F.